# Is it meaningful to use multiprocessing to read multiple files with Python?

Tags: python, file-io, python-multiprocessing

I intent to use multiprocessing to read a set of small files with multiprocesing capabilities of Python. However this is awkward in some sense to me because if the disk is rotational then the bottle neck is the rotation time and even-though I use multiple processes, total read time should be similar with single process read. Am I wrong ? What are your comments?

I addition, do you think using multiprocessing might cause intertwined reading of the files so the contents of these files are skewed in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is sound, but the only way to find out for sure is by benchmarking (that said, it is unlikely that reading many small files in parallel will increase performance over reading them sequentially).

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "intertwined reading", but -- unless there are bugs in your code or the files are being changed while you're reading them -- you will get exactly the same contents irrespective of how you read it.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed right, the *bottleneck* will be **disk-IO**.

However, the only way to really know, is to measure both approaches.

If you have influence on the files, you could go for one larger file as opposed to many smaller files.